# CPU usage spikes

Tags: java, multithreading, cpu

My program is all the time running at max 1% of CPU usage but sometimes since some event inside the program, that i cannot determine, it has 100% usage for about 5-10 seconds every 15 seconds. It looks like a Thread causing usage spikes but i cant determine the source of that(there are 8000 classes so thats quite hard). It's hard to test if problem still exists(for example after making some part of code "dead") because that problem is sometimes starting it's existence after few hours of Virtual Machine lifetime.

Have you got any idea what would help me find the source of that problem?

Comment: sounds like you need a Java profiler

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without more information, it would be impossible to even attempt a guess at the cause of your problem.

I would suggest using a profiler, such as [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/), to determine which thread causes the issue and potentially what the exact circumstances are when it happens.

Using a profiler would tell you for example:

- Which threads are active and taking up CPU resources
- Whether they are VM or application threads
- How much time is spent on garbage collection operations - GC is often a source of CPU usage spikes and therefore latency, although I believe that recent JVMs have improved in that regard.
- Whether there are locking issues
- ...

Comment: i am using VisualVM, most of my Threads have got same Executor so i cant find Thread that is run at the time of the spike.

Comment: Is the spike caused by one of your own threads? Or by a VM one?

Comment: VM, but i just installed JProfiler and it seems to be way better than VisualVM, i think it will help me a lot.

Comment: Yes, but how can you use JProfiler to track down the source of the spikes?  In my scenario I can see the spike in JProfiler telemetry, but after 3 days of this B.S. I have come-up empty handed with clues or leads.

Comment: @JonathanNeufeld: did you try grabbing a thread dump (or even a few of them) during those spikes? If you are a bit lucky, you may manage to grab a thread stacktrace that would give you a hint...

Comment: I found a video on YouTube that explains precisely how to do it in JProfiler.  First you must record _Method Statistics_ and then add _Exceptional Methods_ based on the _Outlier Coefficient_ (larger coefficient means greater variance between maximum execution time and median execution time).  Then the next time you CPU profile, exceptional method calls with high execution time will be distributed individually in the call tree along with their call traces.